# Как получить значение из переменной, которая лежит вне функции?

Tags: javascript

Как получить значение из переменной, которая лежит вне функции?

```
   <select name="cifer" onchange="show(this.value)" >
    <option value="">выбери</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  <script>
   и есть функция
   var s = function show(st) {
   //приходит к нам  из селекта значение например 2
   var a=''; //заводим переменную
   //присваиваем значение из селекта  переменной 
    var a += st;
    }
     console.log(a)//ошибка ,как получить эту двойку вне функции show
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. > как получить значение из переменной которая лежит вне фунункции
2. Обращение к переменной описанной в функции

На первый вопрос ответ прост - глобальные переменные доступны внутри функции, так что просто по имени

```
var myVar = '';
function show(st) { myVar += st; }
show('бла-бла');
console.log(myVar);
```

По второму - нельзя!
Советую ознакомиться с областью видимости переменных - [раз](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78991/), [два](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127482/), [три](http://vvz.nw.ru/Lessons/JavaScript/scope.htm) и [четыре](http://javascript.ru/basic/functions).  
Почему ?
Потому что переменная локальная - то есть она перестаёт существовать после выхода из функции.

Обходное решение - глобальная переменная (см. выше).

PS
Так же советую прочитать как описываются [функции](http://javascript.ru/basic/functions) и [переменные](http://learn.javascript.ru/variables) в JavaScript...
И вообще советую почитать [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru).

PS2
Переменную нельзя описать дважды, то есть **var** следует использовать для переменной один раз...
И ещё момент, меня волнует глубокий смысл вашей функции

```
var s = function show(st) { var a = ''; var a += st; }
```

Что вы ожидали от такой записи?
Вы вообще пытались её в начале проверить в браузере? Заглядывали в консоль вообще?

Answer (score 1):

1.Загнать в window

```
funct() {
 window.a='';
 window.a += st;
}
funct();
console.log(window.a)
```

2.Объявить вне функции

```
var a;
funct() {
 a='';
 a += st;
}
funct();
console.log(window.a)
```

Comment: Если человек не знает основ языка и программирования, не лучше ли что бы он сам разобрался?  
И там ещё входная переменная там есть у функции - **st**...  
И, @danpetruk, вы забыли пояснить, что код эквивалентен и дать [ссылку][1] поясняющие почему к **a** можно обращаться как по имени так и как к свойству объекта **window** ;)  


  [1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/global-object

Comment: АБСОЛЮТНО везде выдаёт undefined

Comment: А не лучше сделать глобальный(в window) обьект и уже туда вынести перменную, чем сразу в window?